# Postfix warning when sending mail: hostname <FQDN> does not resolve to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Tags: debian, postfix, hostname, hosts

Every time I send an email, I get this line in /var/log/mail.warn:

```
postfix/submission/smtpd[xxxxx]: warning: hostname <FQDN> does not resolve to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I've obviously already Google'd the issue; my /etc/host.conf has "multi=on" as the only entry, I've tried to add the following two lines to /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtp_host_lookup = native #(also tried "dns", for that matter)
import_environment = MAIL_CONFIG MAIL_DEBUG MAIL_LOGTAG TZ XAUTHORITY DISPLAY LANG=C RESOLV_MULTI=on
```

Nothing helped. I suspect the issue lies in the nature of the server's config; it's a Hetzner server which has a different internal IP, see here: https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/VServer/en#Why_does_my_VM_have_a_different_IP_from_the_one_shown_in_the_Robot.3F

But I can't figure out how to fix that. I've used this guide for mailserver setup, so most config files are 100% as in here:

https://thomas-leister.de/sicherer-mailserver-dovecot-postfix-virtuellen-benutzern-mysql-ubuntu-server-xenial/

For the sake of completeness, here's /etc/hosts:

```
# IPv4
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
# (old) 172.xx.xx.xx  Debian-85-jessie-64-LAMP
172.xx.xx.xx mysrv.mydomain.tld mysrv
#
# IPv6
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx::2  Debian-85-jessie-64-LAMP
```

Comment: I suspect you are using non-fqdn domain, for example if you run `host <your domain name>` it will say not found, to get rid of this warning you could use the ip or dns provided to you by hetzner. have a look at [this](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#myorigin) to understand better the $myorigin and $myhostaname variables.

Comment: Hm... here's the result: "host domain.tld" yields "domain.tld has address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", "domain.tld mail is handled by 10 mysrv.domain.tld". Looks correct, doesn't it? (The IP address is the public one, not the internal Hetzner address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer my own question (not sure if that's violating any rules or not):

I've replaced the internal Hetzner IP with the public one in /etc/hosts and everything works fine now, the warning is gone. I have no idea why the public one isn't entered there by default, and if there's any drawback to changing that.